# Read data from Google Spreadsheets

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Am looking to read data from Google Spreadsheets. Here are the things I tried so far:

```
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MySpreadsheetIntegration1 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

    SpreadsheetService service =
        new SpreadsheetService("SpreadSheetSample");

    // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

    // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jeo8zOv34wVmIX3rL48GksZgj0ixgHx_cwDCdZyQKCg/edit#gid=0");

    // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
    for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
      // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
      System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get connection time out error. I feel it's some authentication problem.

Can someone please help me on how to achieve this?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jeo8zOv34wVmIX3rL48GksZgj0ixgHx_cwDCdZyQKCg/edit#gid=0) is the link to the spreadsheet I have created for test purposes.
Also lot of code available in Google but none of them works so far.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to actually create an OAuth session to authenticate yourself with google.

Here is the OAuth code I use for my current project!

```
/**
 * Retrieve OAuth 2.0 credentials.
 *
 * @return OAuth 2.0 Credential instance.
 */
static Credential getCredentials() throws IOException {
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    // Step 1: Authorize -->
    String authorizationUrl =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, SCOPES).build();

    // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
    System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

    // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
    String code = in.readLine();
    // End of Step 1 <--

    // Step 2: Exchange -->
    GoogleTokenResponse response =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(transport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
                    code, REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    // End of Step 2 <--

    authenticated = true;
    // Build a new GoogleCredential instance and return it.
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).build()
            .setAccessToken(response.getAccessToken()).setRefreshToken(response.getRefreshToken());
}
```

Then you simply call it like so

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
service.setOAuth2Credentials(getCredentials());
```

Comment: To read more about OAuth2.0 from Google:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize

Or the official website:
http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: How can i read the data if the values are merged? Like the below sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eHshJTxLa7RKrvfX8nju4uLoOmuJzhqcALFs5jP_Y4o/pubhtml